# How do I list all files but only show the fist N characters of the filenames?

Tags: ls

How do I list all files but only show the fist N characters of the filenames?

for example if the filname was `ABC_2015-01-03-08-00-35.csv` in the directory and then I done a `ls` in that directory I would only get this `LTE_2015-01-03` the 1st 14 characters.

I'm thinking I would use the `ls` command but not sure after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cut to do it for you like so:

```
ls | cut -c1-14
```

I'm assuming you don't care about extensions or the like.